# On a django site I am getting socket cluster error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, web, socketcluster

```
Not Found: /socketcluster/
[06/Aug/2020 21:45:44] "GET /socketcluster/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3181
```

this happens every 61 secounds while I am running the django webserver, using "python3 manage.py runserver". I am very new to web development and have no clue what this is or means, any help is appreciated.

P.S. Do I need a db to handle requests for the web server

Answer (score 9):

This is happening for me as well. I'm still looking into the issue and I'll update this when I have a better answer, but I've found a temporary solution.

If you start the local Django server on a different port than the default 8000, the pesky requests go away:
`python manage.py runserver 8001`

Maybe some other process currently running thinks there's a socketcluster server active on post 8000, or something hidden in my codebase.

Comment: Thanks it works for me now, what I had to do was (and I have no clue which one fixed it):
add a sqlite db, refresh dependencies, checkout a new branch and switch back, restart computer

Comment: (i know its kind of late ... but in my opinion the thing that helped you was the computer restart (i did the same and it stopped) .... i think this answer should be marked as the correct one ... so upvote from me and hopefully other ppl with this problem will know the answer now)) ... potentional fix is to check what processes run on the default 8000 port

Comment: Yes this worked! Ty!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and it turned out to be a recently installed chrome extension.